# Select box with first option empty

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-4

How can I set the first option in my select box to an empty value?

I'm getting the data from my DB, and I would like to set the option by default as "Please select one option".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found that `'default'=>'Please select'` doesn't work with the HTML5 required attribute.
This does work:

```
$listOfValues = [1 => 'Choice 1'];
Form::select('fieldname',[null=>'Please Select'] + $listOfValues);
```

If you don't like modern PHP syntax,

```
$listOfValues = array(1 => 'Choice 1');
$listOfValues[null] = 'Please Select';
Form::select('fieldname', $listOfValues);
```

But the point is to have a label for the null value.

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa PHP 5.4 is a requirement for Laravel 4.2 and above anyway.

Comment: and what is $users here? Answer is not complete :(

Comment: It's a list of users @Gediminas, it's the array of keys/values for the select box. Here we're simply prepending [null=>'Please Select'] to the beginning of the array. The value of $users is rather outside the scope of the question

Comment: @darkbluesun I know, but it should beadded to an answer for it to be fully complete! Thank you for understanding :)

Answer (score 32):

If you are using the [HTML package by LaravelCollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html), you do the following..

```
Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...']);
```

Comment: Yes perfect! This is an example of it in action from my app: `{{ Form::select('status', $statuses, null, ['placeholder' => 'Please select ...', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}`

Comment: Just in case this trips anyone else up, "placeholder" is case sensitive..

Comment: Too bad this doesn't add the `disabled` attribute on the default option.

Comment: Nevermind, I just ran into this issue : https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/148

Comment: The placeholder is perfect. But I needed to use an extra trick so the form doesn't give an error when creating new rows: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object... ->  {!!Form::select('field', App\Instance::pluck('name', 'id') , old('field', isset($field->id) ? $field->id : null), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Please Select...'])!!}

Answer (score 22):

There are 2 methods to do this:

```
{{ Form::select('user', array('default' => 'Please select one option') + $users, 'default') }}
```

Or

```
<select>
     <option selected disabled>Please select one option</option>
     @foreach($users as $user)
     <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: "Unsupported operand type" message for this.

Comment: What about when you use a standard list output for values `$levels=Level::all()->lists('level', 'id');`  array_add works for adding on the end like so `$levels = array_add($levels, '0', 'Please select');` but can't find anything for prepend that works

Comment: @martyn, it returns the error probably because the 'array' you are combining it with is not really an array but a collection. If using L5.1 and on Eloquent using `lists()` to get the array, L5.1 `lists` returns a collection not an array. To make it return an array you will need to use the `all()` method: `$users = [null=>'Select' ] + User::lists('name','id')->all();` . You can prepend the default option either at the above stage or in the `Form::select()` stage (but making sure you use the `all()` method.
Read further: http://laraveldaily.com/laravel-5-1-empty-option-in-formselect-with-lists/

Answer (score 16):

For anyone that needs this behavior, this way is working fine:

Controller:

```
$entityArray = Entity::lists('name', 'id');
$entityArray->prepend('Select', 'Select');
```

View:

```
{!! Form::select('entity', $entityArray) !!}
```

Comment: prepending a null key will reset your array keys to start from 0 to n. If you did this `$entityArray->prepend('Select', null);` then your entityArray array will have its key reset to be from 0 to nth.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me on Laravel 5.4.

```
{{ Form::select('agency', $agency, null, [
    'placeholder' => 'Please select ...',
    'class' => 'form-control'
]) }}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Answer (score 5):

**in controller**

```
$data['options']=Entity::pluck('name','id')->prepend('Please Select','');

return view('your_view_blade',$data);
```

**in view blade**

```
{!! Form::select('control_name',$options,null,['class'=>'your_class']) !!}
```

Answer (score 4):

100% result:

In controller:

```
$users = App\User::get()->lists('full_name', 'id')->prepend('Select user','');
return view('name of view')->with('users', $users);
```

In view:

```
{!! Form::select('who', $users, null, ['class' => 'form-control inline']) !!}
```

I´m using "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0" package

Answer (score 3):

In laravel 5.2

This worked for me

```
{!! Form::select('user', $users, null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Please select')) !!}
```

as I just add `placeholder` and it made the trick

Answer (score 2):

For a Laravel 5 collection, you may need to convert the collection to array first.

```
<?php
$defaultSelection = [''=>'Please Select'];
$users = $defaultSelection + $users->toArray();?>
```

and apply $users as

```
{!! Form::select('user', $users); !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.1 i solved it by doing

```
$categories = [''=>''] + Category::lists('name', 'id')->toArray();
return view('products.create', compact('categories'));
```

Or

```
$categories = [''=>''] + Category::lists('name', 'id')->all();
return view('products.create', compact('categories'));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the view

{!! Form::select('qualification_level', $qualification , old('Qualification_Level'), ['class' => 'form-control select2', **'placeholder' => ''**]) !!}

In the Controller
$qualification = \App\Qualification::pluck('name','id')**->prepend('Please Select');**

Comment: it helped me to solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Laerte anwser

You can do it at the `Blade level` just by issuing a command:

```
{!! Form::select('entity', $entityArray) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate the array before the view

or to be messy you could do it in blade @php tags

```
    $users= [null => 'Empty'];

    $dbusers= User::pluck('id', 'name');

    $users= array_merge($users, $dbusers->toArray());

    return view('myview', compact('users'))
```

and then you can do the following in the view

```
{{ Form::select('user',$users, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::select('parent_id', [null=>'Please Select'] + \App\Item::where('1','1')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{ !! Form::select('country', $country, 'GB', ['id' = > 'country', 'class' = > 'form-control select2me']) !!}
```

Here `$country` is array that contains many countries , in this array is *"great britain"* by the id *"GB"* which will be selected by default.