# Disable drop down?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've checked this answer:

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912295/laravel-4-select-box-with-first-option-empty)

But with no luck.

I need the first item in my dropdown to be disabled. How can I do this using the form builder?

```
Form::select('my-select', array('please-select' => 'please select', 'a' => 'apple'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own macro for that. I don't think laravel has any default way of doing it.

```
HTML::macro('mySelect', function($value, $extras)
{
    $build = array();
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $build[] = sprintf('<option>%s</option>', $val);
    }
    $build[0] = sprintf('<option disabled>%s</option>', $value[1]);
    return sprintf('<select>%s</select>', implode("", $build));
});
```

This macro can go to  app > start > global.php of the laravel project.

Hope this helps